# Is there any memory leak between two threads (Buffering, Emptying)

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider the following code please, including two threads buffering_thread (fills up buffer pointer with one message) and sending_thread (empties the buffer):

```
#include "msg.cpp"

msg * buffer= NULL;
byte * send_bytes= NULL;
bool keep_buffering = true;
bool keep_sending = true;
int counter = 0;

void start_buffering() {
    while (keep_buffering){
        while (buffer != NULL && keep_buffering){}
        msg m (counter);
        buffer = &m;
        counter ++;
    }
    std::cout << "Finished start_buffering" << std::endl;
}

void sending() {
    while (keep_sending){
        if (counter > 10){
            keep_buffering = false;
            break;
        }
        if (buffer != NULL){
            HeaderType messageHeader = buffer -> getHeader();
            print(messageHeader);
            send_bytes = (byte *) realloc(send_bytes,DATASIZE + HEADER);
            memcpy (send_bytes, &messageHeader, HEADER);
            memcpy (send_bytes + HEADER,buffer -> getText(), DATASIZE);
            // Do something, suppose for now NOTHING
            free (buffer -> getText());
            buffer = NULL;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Finished sending" << std::endl;
}

int main () {

    std::thread sending_thread(sending);

    std::thread buffering_thread(start_buffering);

    buffering_thread.join();

    keep_sending = false;

    sending_thread.join();

    //free (buffer);
    free (send_bytes);
    return 0;
}
```

where the class `msg` is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#define DATASIZE 10
#define HEADER sizeof(HeaderType)

class msg
{
    private:
        HeaderType header;
        byte * text;    

    public:
        msg(int ID);
        HeaderType getHeader();
        byte * getText();
};

msg::msg(int ID){
    header.mID = ID;
    text = (byte *)malloc (DATASIZE);
    memset (text, '.', DATASIZE);
}

HeaderType msg::getHeader(){
    return header;
}


void print(HeaderType header) {
    std::cout << "Message ID: " << header.mID << std::endl;
}


byte * msg::getText(){
    return text;
}
```

and this is `HeaderType`:

```
typedef struct {
    int mID;
}HeaderType;
```

Valgrind reports:

```
==3809== 20 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3809==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3809==    by 0x80492BD: msg::msg(int) (in /home/linux/LCR-write/src/test)
==3809==    by 0x8049384: start_buffering() (in /home/linux/LCR-write/src/test)
```

Indeed, I guess there must not be any memory leak inside this code. The buffer should always be emptied by `sending_thread`. Would somebody point out the fault please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `start_buffering()` function.

```
while (keep_buffering){
    msg m (counter);
    while (buffer != NULL && keep_buffering){}
    buffer = &m;
    counter ++;
}
```

This loop creates a `msg` and allocates the memory for `text` in it's constructor. Then it waits, and then it will do:

```
    buffer = &m;
    counter ++;
    // end of loop
    msg m (counter);
```

When the loop reaches the end, it starts the next iteration without waiting for anything. The 'old' `msg m` falls out of scope, and a new `msg m` is allocated at the exact same place on the stack than the old one. So the pointer `buffer` is still 'valid' (not really!), pointing to the new `m`. The result is a memory leak for the first `msg m`, and, more importantly, **undefined behaviour**. You may not use things that are not in scope anymore.

Additionally, I would recommend to use 'official' synchronisation and wait mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks @alain. Still the same problem. Even though this was a wrong, but not my problem. Check the edit please.

Comment: You could add `free(text);` to your `~msg()` and write `msg* m = new msg(counter);` in the loop, and `delete buffer;` in `sending()`, instead of `free(buffer->getText())`

Comment: ==4287== 18 (8 direct, 10 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==4287==    at 0x402842F: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==4287==    by 0x8048D79: start_buffering()

Comment: I think the last msg gets lost. Try adding an `if(keep_buffering) {` after the wait, around the rest of the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

you need a destructor for msg that frees the memory allocated for text in the constructor

```
class msg
{
    private:
        HeaderType header;
        byte * text;    

    public:
        msg(int ID);
        HeaderType getHeader();
        byte * getText();
        ~msg() {free(text);}
};
```

Comment: This would result in a double free, because it's freed in `sending()` too.

Comment: indeed it would , i missed that - thats poor design though. text is private implementation detail of msg.

Comment: Indeed, I intended to delete the destructor to highlight more on my problem with freeing. Anyway, Thanks @pm100.